# DHIS2: Data Entry form Management - Data elements, totals, indicators

Tags: dhis2

I am creating a data entry form and have several Yes/No questions that I have built as data elements. When building these data elements, I have stipulated that the "Value Type" should be 'Yes/No' and the "Aggregation Operator" should be 'none'.

When I go to design the data entry form (under Data Sets), some of the data elements only appear under the "Totals" tab in the "insert data elements, totals and indicators" box.

When testing the data entry by inputting random data on the data entry form, these boxes appear with a '0' in them already and dont have the option of changing to either a 'Yes' or a 'No'.

How do I change these data elements to appear under the "data elements" tab in the "insert data elements, totals and indicators" box, and make them into simple 'Yes/No' selection box questions?

Comment: Which version of DHIS 2 is this? Which browser and version?

Comment: Can you try to clear the browser cache according to this? https://www.dhis2.org/tutorials/how-to-really-clear-browser-cache